# Convert csv files to another csv format on hdfs

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce

I have to implement a CSV files converter to be run on a hadoop cluster. The main lines are:

- I have a bunch of csv files on hdfs, with arbitrary content.
- I know how to convert them in a "standard" one (i.e with specified rows) using java code.
- The conversion requires some parameters (around 10 or 15), different for each file.
- I don't mind the output files to be segmented.
- But I'd like them to have a `input-filename[##].csv` name to distinguish them for later processing/visualization.

My question is: *what would be the best way to do that?*

Being new to hadoop, I am thinking of doing this using map reduce, but I have issues about the output format. On the other hand, I could use spark (with my java code used in scala). It seems easy to code but then I don't know much how to do it.

Opinion with pointer on the main task to be implemented, from (more) experienced user would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a little too vague, as this depends a lot on what tools your cluster currently has installed , the size of your CSVs, whether you'll be running the job often or just once. Certainly MapReduce isn't really useful here, as you don't have anything to key on. You could write a standalone mapper class. However this seems overly-complex. Based on what you've said, I'd go for Pig as it will be lightweight and probably quickest to code. No point writing lots of Java for something as simple as this.

Comment: You're right, I'm too vague but this is because I don't know what information is relevant. I put pig aside because the conversion is not that simple and I already have code for it.

Comment: Ah if you already have code and access to Spark, go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed really simple with spark:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil;

import java.io.File;

public class Converter {
    static String appName = "CSV-Conversion";  // spark app name
    static String master = "local";            // spark master 

    JavaSparkContext sc;

    /**
     * Init spark context
     */
    public Converter(){
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master);
        sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    }

    /**
     * The conversion using spark
     */
    public void convertFile(String inputFile, String outputDir){
        JavaRDD<String> inputRdd = sc.textFile(inputFile);
        JavaRDD<String> outputRdd = inputRdd.map(Converter::convertLine);
        outputRdd.saveAsTextFile(outputDir);
    }

    /**
     * The function that convert each file line.
     *
     * It is static (i.e. does not requires 'this') and does not use other object.
     * If external objects (or not static method) are required, they must be
     * serializable so that a copy can be send to each worker node.
     * It is however better to avoid or at least minimize such data transfer.
     */
    public static String convertLine(String line){
        return line.toUpperCase();
    }


    /**
     * As a stand-alone app
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if(args.length!=2) {
            System.out.println("Invalid number of arguments. Usage: Converter inputFile outputDir");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String inputFile = args[0];
        String outputDir = args[1];

        FileUtil.fullyDelete(new File(outputDir));

        Converter c = new Converter();
        c.convertFile(inputFile,outputDir);
    }
}
```

I made a [simple maven project for it in github](https://github.com/julien-diener/spark-csvconverter)

Answer (score 1):

Spark is a good choice. It provides you more flexibility with fast processing as well.